# strange optional behaviour in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, option-type

I have created my own class in Swift as below.

```
class Product: NSObject {

    var product_id:Int?
    var product_number:String?
    var product_price:Float?
    var product_descrption:String?
}
```

Now i am setting value in each property like this

```
        let p=Product()
        p.product_id=1
        p.product_price=220.22
        p.productdescrption="Some description"
        p.product_number="W2_23_233"
```

But when i get the value from price then for price i get value like **"Optional 220.22"** But i don't get appended word **"Optional"** in description".So to resolve this i added **"!"** for unwrapping the value of **float** but i did not have to do this for **String** please tell why this is happening?

Comment: You didn't have to unwrap the string because whatever function you using for that string dont require unwraped value, you should use optional type when declaring only if the value can be nil, if not then don't need use it

Comment: if you print `p.product_number` it will also print with `optional`.

Comment: I dont understand why someone have voted it down.

Comment: @DheerajKumar Did my answer help you? If so please put it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing any of these values should say Optional(...). If you are assigning the values to a label, that will not include the Optional(...), The reason that it shows Optional(...) when you print the value using print(), is just to show you its an optional. For safety, instead of using the !, try using if lets.

An example with your code,

```
if let id = p.product_id {
    print(id) //Does not contain Optional()
}
```

You can also combine them, to do them all at one time. (Only do this if you don't want to print unless all values are non-nil)

```
if let id = p.product_id,
   let price = p.product_price, 
   let description = p.productdescrption,
   let productNumber = p.product_number {
       //Enter code here that does something with these values
}
```

Note, if you aren't on swift 3, I believe you only have to write let on the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you print any optional variable without unwrapping no matter what type it is, Optional will be appended to the variable's value.

`print(p.product_price)` will print **Optional(220.220001)**

`print(p.product_descrption)` will print **Optional("Some description")**

To print only value you need to unwrap the optional variables.

`print(p.product_price!)` will print **220.22**

`print(p.product_descrption!)` will print **Some description**

This forced unwrapping will only work if the optionals does not contain `nil`. Otherwise it will give you a runtime error.
So to check for `nil` you can use `if let` statement.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what type of variable. If you assign a value to an optional variable, It always enclosed with Optional(...)

Optional without forced unwrapping:

```
print("product_price = \(p.product_price) \n product_descrption = \(p.product_descrption)")
```

Output:
product_price = Optional(220.22)
product_descrption = Optional(Some description)

Optional with forced unwrapping:

```
print("product_price = \(p.product_price!) \n product_descrption = \(p.product_descrption!)")
```

Output:
product_price = 220.22
product_descrption = Some description